# rewrite two variable with RewriteRule

Tags: php

I have a code like this:

```
  echo "  <td width='57%' height='126' class='bord' ><a href='$category_name-$id.htm'
  class='title_style'>" . $title . "</a><br />
   ";
```

So, $category_name is the name of categories from database. So it changes!

I need to rewrite it using RewriteRule. I've tried something like this

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)\.htm$  classified.php?id=$1 [L]
```

EX:
Let say $category_name = Cars and $id =15 then the url should look: Cars-15.htm

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you only wanted to get the numeric part of the incoming path name.

Your regex is correct so far, but you used the wrong placeholder. `$1` is for the first capture group, the category in your case. And `$2` contains the second match groups content, the numeric id.

So your RewriteRule ought to be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+)\.htm$  classified.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Which could be simplified further btw:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)-(\d+)\.htm$  classified.php?id=$2 [L]
```

(Though also matches underscores in the category part then.)

Comment: Thank you Mario. It worked only if $category_name is one word. How about if $category_name = 'Health care' or $category_name= 'Cars/Bikes'? I've tried to allow space but the I get server error: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-^/ _]+)-([0-9]+)\.htm$  classified.php?id=$2 [L]

Comment: Got itRewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-\s]+)-(\d+)\.htm$   classified.php?id=$2 [L]